# input css rendering inconsistencies across browsers

Tags: css, input, webkit, positioning

The input button is incorrectly higher than the input field.

I used Firebug to copy all the styles applied to the 3 elements in question (the containing `p` element and the 2 child `input` elements) to replicate the problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/XBjz3/

I have a feeling it's to do with me using negative relative positioning on the input button.

Displays as it should in

- Firefox 12
- Chrome 19
- Internet Explorer 9

Displays wrong in

- Android 2.3.5 browser
- iOS 5.1 browser
- Safari 5.1.7
- Opera 11.6

It's strange that it displays fine in Chrome when the 3 other webkit browsers renders it incorrectly.

Comment: To me the vertical position seems to be inconsistent, not the height.

Comment: I did say negative relative positioning on the input button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution that looks exactly the same as intended.

http://jsfiddle.net/XBjz3/8/

Here are the changes from the original.

```
#pwbox-33 {
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
.pw-submit {
    top: 0;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

Tested to work on Firefox, Chrome, IE, Safari, Opera, and Android stock browser.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```
top:-0.5em;
```

You can use

```
bottom : 0.4em;
```

As its not good practice to use negative values for position.

Comment: Doesn't fix the problem. Tried in Opera and Safari.

Answer (score 0):

check this one i hope this will help you..

**HTML**

```
<p>
    <input type="password" class="pw-box" id="pwbox-33" name="post_password">
    <input type="submit" class="pw-submit" value="Submit" name="Submit">
</p>
```

**CSS**

```
p {

    width:50%;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 1%;
    padding-right: 1%;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 1em;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    margin:20px 0 0 20px;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.1);

}
#pwbox-33 {
    width: 200px;
    border:0;
    background: #606D80;
    border-top:solid 1px  #1F3453;
    color: #DCE0E6;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0.5em;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #1F1F20;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.pw-submit{
cursor: pointer;
    background:#2B4C7E;
    color: #DCE0E6;
    padding: 0.5em 1em;
    position: absolute;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #1F1F20;
    top: -0.3em;
    border:0;
    font-size:12px;
    font-family:arial;
    left:200px;
    border-bottom:solid 0.5em #0E2952;
    outline:0;

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YjNJ5/3/

Comment: It doesn't look the same as the original though. In Firefox, the input field is positioned higher up and the submit button is overlapping the input field.